# CDatabase Leak even after calling Close

Tags: c++, mfc, memory-leaks, 64-bit

My application leaks while executing the following code piece. Memory is not released even after calling `Close()` on the `CDatabase`.

*How can I correct the leak without destroying the CDatabase object?*

```
CDatabase db;
int count = 2000;
for (int i=0; i <count; ++i)
{
    BOOL bRes = db.OpenEx("DSN=ICEDBServer;UID=sa;PWD=ICEConnect200");
    db.Close();
}
```

The call stack of the leak location is given below

```
+  133154 ( 133154 -      0)   2001 allocs  BackTrace477
+    2001 (   2001 -      0)    BackTrace477    allocations

    ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+00001292
    ntdll!LdrpCopyUnicodeString+000000B1
    ntdll!LdrpResolveDllName+000002CE
    ntdll!LdrpMapDll+000002C1
    ntdll!LdrpLoadDll+00000251
    ntdll!LdrLoadDll+000001C8
    kernel32!LoadLibraryExW+0000024D
    ODBC32!LoadDriver+00000235
    ODBC32!SQLDriverConnectW+00000C11
    ODBC32!SQLDriverConnect+000001BB
    mfc90!CDatabase::Connect+0000009E (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp, 745)
    mfc90!CDatabase::OpenEx+00000089 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp, 289)
    testApp!CtestAppDlg::OnBnClickedButton1+0000006A (d:\test\testapp\testapp\testappdlg.cpp, 162)
    mfc90!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg+000000C4 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\cmdtarg.cpp, 82)
    mfc90!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg+000001A4 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\cmdtarg.cpp, 381)
    mfc90!CPropertySheet::OnCmdMsg+00000032 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgprop.cpp, 814)
    mfc90!CWnd::OnCommand+00000100 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp, 2364)
    mfc90!CWnd::OnWndMsg+0000005F (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp, 1769)
    mfc90!CWnd::WindowProc+00000038 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp, 1755)
    mfc90!AfxCallWndProc+00000100 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp, 240)
    mfc90!AfxWndProc+00000059 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp, 402)
    mfc90!AfxWndProcBase+00000053 (f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxstate.cpp, 441)
    USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+000001F9
    USER32!DispatchClientMessage+000000C3
    USER32!_fnDWORD+0000002D
    ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+00000000
    USER32!ZwUserMessageCall+0000000A
```

Answer (score 0):

When your program opens the first database connection, it loads database libraries into memory. The following connections do not really need a lot of memory because of connection pooling. Closing all connections does not unload everything you loaded before in an instant, and some parts stay in memory until your program exits.

Comment: Some memory is leaked 2000 times. I got this information from UMDH. So I don't think it is due to dll loading